# Set IsModified to false on few columns of entity in EF 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How can i set IsModified to false on certain properties of my EntityObject.

here is my code

```
message.To = message.To.Decrypt(encryptionKey);
```

now i want to set message.To as IsModified= false, so that while save changes, EF will ignore changes to this column.

I am using EF 4.0

Comment: I would not do this, especially when encryption is involved. Create a view model or DTO class that has the decrypted message. Else you'll always run the risk that decrypted messages get saved.

Comment: Always? Not really, although I admit it needs a bit of work to prevent. See my solution.

Comment: @Gert Arnold - Exactly, i got an issue that my decrypted messages are being saved back to database. That is the reason i want to set it unmodified.

Comment: What I mean is that it's easily overlooked when the code is modified in future development. In general it should always be avoided to have entities in a state that they _absolutely_ should not be saved. It's a time bomb.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! As far as I realized **EF 4.0** doesn't have such straightforward solution for this (fortunately later versions of EF solved this in a nice manner).

Anyway, I'll tackle this problem in 3 stages:

**1-** if `message` is already attached to the context and since the time of attachement it has been modified, we first record its modified properties in a list

```
var modifiedProps = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(message).GetModifiedProperties().Where(p=>p.Equals('To')==false).ToList();
```

If it was not attached, we attach it

```
context.Attach(message); // the sate of the message will be UnChanged
var modifiedList = any property changed based on what you have done so far;
```

2- Change the state of the object to `UnChanged`, this way every property is excluded from `Update`'s `SET`clause

```
var entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(message);
entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
```

3- Mark previously modified properties as `Modified` except `To` property

```
modifiedProps.ForEach(p=> entry.SetModifiedProperty(p));
```

Finally save your changes through `context.SaveChanges();`

**Edit:**

I forgot to exclude property `To` in Step #1. It is now corrected

Comment: But i want to set unchanged while SetModifiedProperty marks the property as changed

Comment: @Patel This is what the code actually does through step #2. When the state of entity changes to `UnChanged` in Step #2, **every property** is marked `UnChanged`. In Step #3, some of them are re-marked `Changed` except `To`

Comment: Oppsss.... got an issue. When the entity state is changed to UnChanged it also restores the old value for all modified properties which is not what i want

Comment: @Patel Too Wierd!!! I tested it and I can say for sure restoring back to origional values is something that cannot be done automatically. Honestly, doing undo needs writing a bunch of lines of code. May be there are some events or methods being called but you are not aware of.

Comment: ya, my mistake. I am having another issue. Before encryption, i am checking if string is base64 encoded or not. And there is issue with it

Answer (score 0):

the following did the job for me

wrote the below line immediately after decrypting the properties

```
_db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(message, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

setting the whole object as unmodifed. Though this is not what i asked for, but EF 4.0 does not provide facility to set a Property as Unchanged directly.